# ¿Cómo puedo recorrer en un foreach los valores que retorno un WCF?

Tags: asp.net, wcf

Soy un principiante en servicios web
he realizado un servicio *WCF* en `C#`, tengo un método que retorna una lista

```
 public List<alumnos> Consultar_usuarios_aula(int codigo_aula)
    {
        SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection("Server = tcp:xxx.database.windows.net,1433; Initial Catalog = XX; Persist Security Info = False; User ID = xx; Password =xx; MultipleActiveResultSets = False; Encrypt = True; TrustServerCertificate = False; Connection Timeout = 30;");
        List<alumnos> alumno = new List<alumnos>();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
        string query = "select * from tb_alumnos where cod_aula ="+codigo_aula;
        cmd = new SqlCommand(query, cn);
        SqlDataReader dr;
        try
        {
            cn.Open();
            dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            while (dr.Read())
            {
                alumno.Add(new alumnos()
                {
                    id_alumno = Convert.ToInt32(dr["codigo"].ToString()),
                    nombre = dr["apellido"].ToString(),
                    apellido = dr["nombre"].ToString(),
                    id_aula = dr["cod_aula"].ToString()
                });
            }
            dr.Close();
            cn.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
        }

        return alumno;
    }
```

Sin embargo tengo dificultades para recorrer esa lista desde mi cliente *web* que es un **asp.net**

he agregado una referencia:

```
    ServiceReference1.Service1Client lista_alumnos_aula = new ServiceReference1.Service1Client();
lista_alumnos_aula.Consultar_usuarios_aula(1);
```

Pero cómo puedo hacer para recorrer en un *foreach* esta respuesta.

```
foreach (var x in lista)
            {

            }
```

Agradeceré tanto sus comentarios.

Answer (score 0):

```
ServiceReference1.Service1Client lista_alumnos_aula = new ServiceReference1.Service1Client();
    List<alumnos> AlumnosList = new List<alumno>();

    AlumnosList = lista_alumnos_aula.Consultar_usuarios_aula(1);

    foreach (var x in AlumnosList)
                {

                }
```